# Is there such a thing as a unique browser $_SESSION id?

Tags: php, session, browser

I am working on add to favorites add-on (where posts will be added to favorites by signed in users), but then I saw that craigslist lets anyone add favorites without them being signed in. How do they do that? Is there a unique $_SESSION id for a browser? Sorry if it's a silly question.

As an example: http://orlando.craigslist.org/search/jjj (Click on any star to add to favorites. May not be available in IE 11).

Comment: Yep, different browser, different session id for PHP

Answer (score 0):

They are just using a session, you should be able to check this by looking what cookies they are storing on your computer.

Comment: Just to store a session cookie how do I implement this in the given example: `<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['userid'] = ...

?>` What do I place instead of ...?

Comment: @ HPierce and others. What should I use to store a cookie for this or that browser? Shouldn't it be unique for every user? Otherwise they will start seeing the same favorites.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in $_SESSION persist only for the current session. If the users closes the browser and reopen it a new session is generated. So $_SESSION is not the right place for your answer.

There is $_ENV where you can get the clients ip address and general browser data from. In most cases this is enough to identify a single user. If you keep track of these data you can prevent users from giving multiple votes.

Comment: [`$_ENV`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php) appears to be a superglobal for server environment variables - are you should you've not thinking of [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/reserved.variables.server)?

Comment: Some of my comments disappeared. Strange. What would I use in this example: `<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['userid'] = $_COOKIE[$ck_id];

?>` That works if a person has an account. What would I use to retrieve a unique cookie? And how do I store a unique cookie for this or that browser that will identify them as unique users?